# Reinstalling OS (without wiping) on whole-drive-encrypted Linux Mint system

Tags: linux-mint, reinstall, whole-drive-encryption

I installed Linux Mint 18.1 with the whole-drive encryption option.

Suppose I want to try out a different, but structurally compatible Linux (say, Mint 17) without wiping everything, just installing overtop and leaving my home directory intact.

Is that possible?

Comment: It depends what encryption scheme did you use, and what kind of partitionning you implemented when installing linux mint

Comment: You're asking for so much library & dependency headaches if you install one OS over top on another without really knowing what's going on.  If you just want to preserve your home directory then backup, install, restore is probably the cleanest way.  Or create a /home partition & move your data there then install.

Comment: @netmonk I have no idea, whatever the installer gives.  I don't recall there being an option to choose a scheme, just 'encrypted' or 'not'.  As for partitioning, I picked the default non-UEFI layout for Mint taking up the whole disk.

Comment: @DeanBrundage OK, but for your latter scenario, is it possible to create a /home partition when the whole drive is already in use and encrypted?  (I think I face the same question/problem in either scenario...)  I was trying to avoid the restore time if possible.